# Having challenges trying to login my Elementary OS password

Tags: loops, authentication, elementary-os

I have been trying to login to my PC. It keeps looping. Whenever I type the password and try to log in, it accepts it, brings up a blank screen and then returns to the login screen
Have tried using Ctrl+Alt+F1 to log in from there but still not working...
Guys help out

Comment: Have you tried using `Ctrl+Akt+F2´ to login from a terminal? Can you login from outside (e.g. via SSH when enabled)? What did you change at your system?

Comment: Yeah, have tried to login from terminal... Its still rejecting my password

Comment: I changed nothing to my notice... The last thing I remember doing was that I installed Nvidia and then I was watching some YouTube videos later on... I decided to open my settings but it was opening up... Then I decided to reboot my system, thinking it will fix it... After rebooting, that's when I encountered this issue

Comment: Rejecting the password from terminal is strange. Possibly you use another keyboard setting for the terminal. Sometimes the keyboard layout is different within the terminal - you can try the letters for your password entering the name and see if the characters are right. I have also stumbled upon it before, as I often switch between English and German keyboard. What you can also try to start a Linux from USB stick and mount the disk, saving your data for a backup if necessary.

Comment: My password worked from the terminal now... I was using a wrong user for the login before... But the problem is what do I do next

Comment: OK. Thanks alot  for the assistance so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it guys... I used

sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*

sudo apt install elementary-desktop

Comment: Wish I could log into my terminal to try that. I think I'm entering the wrong username, it's not the name that appear on the login screen apparently. How do you know your login name?